# execution python application from browser

Tags: python, django

I have written a python console based program. It takes few arguments (like file name ) for execution.
I want to run it from the browser...
How can I parse this arguments and execute that python code
Any clues..approaches.
Thanks

Comment: Execute Python just like Javascript in a browser? If that's what you mean, that's not possible... But there is an interesting [Python to Javascript compiler](http://pyjs.org/).

Comment: @JohnDoe: I am trying that out.. but I am facing a weird problem.. Its example scripts run just fine.. but then if i use its library in a program... then the is some python-hulahop which it says is missing and I am not able to find it anywhere for ubuntu.. :(

Comment: How about [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/)? Although, Pyjamas still looks like the best bet...

Comment: And if what you meant was more like a server side Python application, I use [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) for that. But client side Python scripting [isn't really feasible](http://books.google.com/books?id=fzUCGtyg0MMC&pg=PA437&lpg=PA437&dq=python+client+side+script+internet+explorer&source=bl&ots=Y221r-y9yw&sig=GZtEidkb3N5KypJBvyaBOKOvsHE&hl=en&ei=pvB5SpSqH5-Ntgfag92WCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3#v=onepage&q=python%20client%20side%20script%20internet%20explorer&f=false). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should clarify your problem. At least i don't fully understand why you want to run a terminal program in the browser?

But if you want to reuse some code you have already written you could use a micro framework like [**Flask**](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#a-minimal-application).

Check this example from flask's docs:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

So you could write a simple view that accepts the arguments you need and the view would then call your code and return whatever you want, most likely an http response.

Comment: sweeet.. exactly what i needed :)

Comment: wow..this thing is light weight and pretty straightforward :)