# Python http server responding to post requests without installing any third party modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, http

I have Python 2.7.9 running on a linux box. Now I need to start a http server to accept post requests with payloads (post body). However, due to some restriction, I cannot use pip to install some third party modules. Can I achieve this with Python out of the box?

Comment: That is a very silly restriction. As viach points out you can definitely to it with standard-library modules, but you shouldn't expect it to be very efficient.

Comment: Use [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/), the one file http server framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it could be done with `BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler` from Python standard library.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31393963/3070670, nice working example is described there.