# Get a RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without" after webdriver click

Tags: python, webdriver, click

I have this simple python selenium code. After "driver.find_element_by_id('btnIniciar').click()" every coding using webdriver return a raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without".
 In this example, I am just trying to take a print screen of the brownser.

Even webdriver.close() after click() line is not working (same error message). IF I take away the click() line off, everything wents fine. So, I conclude the problem is in the click().

I know that when clicking on "Iniciar Teste" button it will run a javascript to evaluate internet speed. 
Any ideas ?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from datetime import datetime

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.brasilbandalarga.com.br/bbl/')
driver.find_element_by_id('btnIniciar').click()
time.sleep(60)
figura = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.png")
print(figura)
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('/tmp/'+figura)
```

The complete error message:

```
$ python3 ./bandalarga.py 
20180620_122229.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bandalarga.py", line 22, in <module>
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file('/home/santana/NET/'+figura)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1010, in get_screenshot_as_file
    png = self.get_screenshot_as_png()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1042, in get_screenshot_as_png
    return base64.b64decode(self.get_screenshot_as_base64().encode('ascii'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1052, in get_screenshot_as_base64
    return self.execute(Command.SCREENSHOT)['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 472, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 496, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1197, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 266, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

Comment: Hi,
Refer to 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48105448/python-http-server-client-remote-end-closed-connection-without-response-error