# Python requests library giving error "Remote end closed connection without response"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am doing a post call with the help of requests library

```
import time

def retry_on_connection_errors(url, data):
    # data consists of dictionary with 20+ key value pairs
    retries = 0
    while retries < 5:
        try:
            response = requests.post(
                url,
                json=data,
                verify=False,
                headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36"}
            )
            return response
        except:
            retries += 1
            time.sleep(1)

    raise Exception("Maximum retries exceeded")
```

even after 5 retries it gives an error

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

and

```
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

I am using **python 3.7** and **requests 2.24.0**

Looked into this answer but did not help:
[Python HTTP Server/Client: Remote end closed connection without response error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48105448/python-http-server-client-remote-end-closed-connection-without-response-error)

Comment: If that other question doesn't help you, perhaps there is little you can do. The error message says that it is the remote end (presumably outside of your control) which is closing the connection. Without a [mcve] it is impossible to know what is happening.

Comment: @JohnColeman in other question, the answers says to add send_response(code, message=None) but. where should i add it. that is what i am not understanding

Comment: That other question involves both client-side and server-side code, with the problem seeming to be with the server-side code. Your code seems to be just client-side.

Comment: @JohnColeman anything you can suggest? that will help me out?